# WPF TPL WebBrowser Control Error: calling thread must be STA

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, browser, task-parallel-library

I've got the following problem:
I want to download a web site with the WebBrowser Control (WPF) in the Background and parse the site afterwards. The download should be in a "tight loop". I needn't display the page. I only need the HTML source as a string. The problem is that the site dynamically adds content with JavaScript after it's loaded, that's why I use this approach.
This  should actually work with several sites simultaneously.

In my following Code there's the error:"The calling thread must be STA, because many UI components require this".

I know if I change the TaskScheduler to the current context I get no error message.

But how can I download the HTML Source in the background?

**ADDITION**
I have to add it to a e.g. StackPanel withoud this addition it doesn't work

```
stackpanel.Children.Add(wb2);
```

Any ideas?

Thank you in advance

```
private void Button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {Task.Factory.StartNew(
                    () =>
                    {
                        WebBrowser wb2 = new WebBrowser();  // That's where I get the error essage
                        wb2.Source = new Uri(MySite);
                        wb2.LoadCompleted += new LoadCompletedEventHandler(wb_LoadCompleted);

                    }, token, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning, TaskScheduler.Default);
            }
        }

void wb_LoadCompleted(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            WebBrowser w = sender as WebBrowser;
            HtmlDocument document = new HtmlDocument(w.Document);
```

**UPDATE**

I tried it like this with the StaTaskScheduler nonetheless get no UI update Any deas where my mistake is and postes it in an extra thread

[StaTaskScheduler (TPL Extension) and WebBrowser Control WPF - Wrong Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7032863/stataskscheduler-tpl-extension-and-webbrowser-control-wpf-wrong-thread)

Thank you!

Comment: I don't want to give an "answer" because this is not my area. Maybe you need to Dispatch your LoadedCompleted content. I never used Task or WebBrowser so its just a guess :) Another way to load something in the Background, which is also the WPF way, is to use a BackgroundWorker.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The TPL in this case should replace the Backgroundworker, etc.

I get the Error Message at WebBrowser wb2 = new WebBrowser();

Answer (score 0):

The `WebBrowser` is already asynchronous, though I believe it *would* execute scripts on the UI thread.

If you want to split it off into a truly separate thread, you can use [STAThreadScheduler](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2010/04/07/9990421.aspx). It sounds like you'd want one (STA) thread per web site.

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer. The  STAThreadScheduler I never heard of before ... I'm a beginner ... 

Does your first sentence mean that It already does what I want it to do without me adding TPL code? The Control needn't execute anything on the ui thread. I add the parse content later to a grid. It just hase to to the job in the background without interrupting any other activity

Comment: Correct. The `WebBrowser` will download the web page in the background and raise the `LoadCompleted` event when it's done. The TPL shouldn't be necessary unless `WebBrowser` is executing a lot of script code on the UI thread (I'm not sure if it would or if the script code would be run in the background, too).

Comment: Thank you, I still have 2 additional question: I have to add the control to a StackPanel or the like in order to make it works. So if I need 20 WebSites I have to add 20 Controls. Do I have to add it into the XAML code or is there a way around it.
the second one is: Can I block certain images or similar things when downloading in order to speed up the process. In my case it sometimes takes a long time until the whole site loads but I don't need the whole site. Thank you in advance

Comment: You can add controls at runtime. I don't know the answer to the 2nd question; I suggest you open another question on SO.

Comment: Thanks but why do I have to add it into the RootLayout. Otherwise it didn't work for me?