# StaTaskScheduler (TPL Extension) and WebBrowser Control WPF - Wrong Thread

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, task-parallel-library

I want to download a web site with the WebBrowser Control (WPF) in the Background and parse the site afterwards. The download should be in a "tight loop". I only need the source as a string. I tried it with the following code which didn't give me the results. 
If I don't use it with StaTaskScheduler the program seems to freez during the loop.
Any Ideas ?

Thank you

```
StaTaskScheduler sta = new StaTaskScheduler(numberOfThreads: 1); 
private void Button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        { 
   for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
            {
                Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                {
                    WebBrowser wb3 = new WebBrowser();
                    wb3.Source = new Uri("MyURL");
                    n++;
                    wb3.LoadCompleted += new LoadCompletedEventHandler(wb_LoadCompleted);
                }, CancellationToken.None, TaskCreationOptions.None, sta);
            }
        }

void wb_LoadCompleted(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e)
    {

 WebBrowser w = sender as WebBrowser;
  HtmlDocument document = new HtmlDocument(w.Document);

blockingCollection.Add(document.Body.OuterHtml);

        Task.Factory.StartNew(
           () =>
           {
               while (!blockingCollection.IsCompleted)
               {
                   string dlcode;
                   Thread.Sleep(500);
                   if (blockingCollection.TryTake(out dlcode))
                   {
    // tb is a TextBox
                         Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => { tb.Text = dlcode; }));
                   }
               }
           }, CancellationToken.None, TaskCreationOptions.None, TaskScheduler.Default);
```

}

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend not using the `WebBrowser` for this, but rather just use a `WebClient` directly.  This is easiest done by making a routine to wrap the download data in a Task:

```
Task<string> DownloadStringAsync(Uri address)
{
     TaskCompletionSource<string> tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<string>();
     WebClient client = new WebClient();

     // Note that you can add error checking here by looking at e.Error/etc, and setting the cancel/error in tcs appropriately...
     client.DownloadStringCompleted += (o,e) => tcs.SetResult(e.Result);
     client.DownloadStringAsync(address);

     return tcs.Task;
}
```

With this, you should be able to just use these tasks directly, and set their results into the BC on completion.  This would be far simpler than trying to spin of a `WebBrowser` control, which is intended for visual use.

Comment: Reed is correct.  The WebBrowser has visual elements meant to interact with the UI thread, even if you do not have it showing.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but the problem is that my site is an ASP.NET site which loads the content dynamically and if I use a normal Http Request I get empty string without content.
Sorry that I forgot to mention this. That's why I would like to use this solution. However I need a fast solution as well. And to me it was rather slow. If you have another idea to solve this problem I'd be very happy. I'm at a loss right now :(

Comment: Is it possible to use maybe MSHMTL o the like to download the website completely and the return the source as a string. That means use an "engine to interpret the site" without displaying it?

Comment: @user774326: You shouldn't get an empty string - you should get some type of header information at a minimum.  Try using `WebRequest` to get the data, and check the returned headers, too...

Comment: What I meant is that I get a string back but what's missing is for instance a whole table with information. The information is only displayed if JavaScript is enabled. If it's disabled the vital information is missing again
I'm sorry that I didn't explain it well enough in my previous post but over here it's 1:30 o'clock at night.

Comment: @user774326: There's probably a call (you can check the JS) to populate the data.  You'd just need to request it directly...  The results you get should tell you where to go for that.

Comment: hmm sounds interesting ... I'll try it tomorrow. If that Doesn't work is there a solution when it comes to interpreting the site like a browser without the visual parts
Thank you for your help!